# Is It possible login Django admin via PyQt5?

Tags: python, django, pyqt5, pyside

I'd like to know if it's possible to login to Django via PyQt5. I have been trying a few things but without much success. Below, I try a solution with PyQt5's QtNetwork. This is my code:

```py
import json
import sys

import requests
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork
from django.test import Client
from querystring import querystring


class AppLogin(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Login in the Desktop Application'
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 300
        self.width = 380
        self.height = 180
        self.username = None
        self.password = None
        self.button = None
        self.nam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        # Create an username textbox
        self.username = QLineEdit(self)
        self.username.move(20, 20)
        self.username.resize(280, 40)
        self.username.setPlaceholderText('Usuário')

        # Create a password textbox
        self.password = QLineEdit(self)
        self.password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.password.move(20, 80)
        self.password.resize(280, 40)
        self.password.setPlaceholderText('Senha')

        # Create a button in the window
        self.button = QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.button.move(20, 140)

        # connect button to function login
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def login(self):
        # User and passwd in my desktop app
        user = self.username.text()
        passwd = self.password.text()
        
        # My Django app Url 
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login"
        data = {'username': user, 'password': passwd}

        # Here, I use QtNetWork to takes request
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        req.setHeader(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader,
                      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

        self.nam.finished.connect(self.handle_response)
        self.nam.post(req, data)

    # Function to reply error
    def handle_response(self, reply):
        error = reply.error()
        # Doesn't entry here
        if error == QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NoError:
            print("success!!!")
        
        # Neither entry here 
        else:
            QMessageBox.question(
                self, 'Error', "Unauthenticated user!", QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok
            )
            self.username.setText("")
            self.password.setText("")
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = AppLogin()
    ex()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Explaining better... My problem was creating an application with PyQt5 or Pyside for a job test, which consumed a web authentication service (Django, Flask, etc.). There should be a window in the desktop app for username and password that consults this information. What I sent them was an application that queries my local database, just looking for the username ([code here](https://github.com/thalescast/pyqt5_login)). However, I'd like to know if there is a way following this line of code above.

Comment: share django project

Comment: Hi @ellyanesc, Thanks for the comment! My code in PyQt5 comes down to the one here, but my project django can be viewed [here] (https://github.com/thalescast/django_and_pyqt)

Comment: I have a curiosity: Why do you want to login?

Comment: Ok, I have no problem in answer your question. This was a test of job, but I didn't do the way correct. So, I'd like to know how to do and if it's possible. If you can help me, I appreciate!

Comment: is that I suspect that your underlying problem is another, I suspect that you want the PyQt5 application to interact with the server to receive or send information. Am I correct? If so, there are better alternatives such as a REST API or using QWebEngineView

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I edited my question. I don't think I was clear enough. Sorry! However, testing should be done with PyQt5 or Pyside.

Comment: mmm, I still have doubts, with your current methodology is to do scraping that may not have a unique solution since there are many authentication systems. To be clear, can you modify the authentication system of the WEB? It does not ask that you have the knowledge but that the WEB is managed by you or your work team.

Comment: I know it's not easy to understand and there must be other ways to solve it, but the requirement for the job vacancy was to create a pyqt or pyside app that had a username and password screen (login button and show if user registered or not) and authenticate with the web application that should be Django or Flask.

Comment: Okay, you want authentication to be done using django and flask and the UI is done with PyQt / PySide, from which it can be concluded that there is no need to have a login view on the WEB so in these cases it is better ( that is, simpler and scalable) to implement a REST API Would it be correct for my response to implement a REST API in django / flask and for the UI written in PyQt / PySide to authenticate and consume services? It seems that you do not understand the whole requirement.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I didn't get it that way, because they didn't talk about REST API, but I can try this solution instead. In fact, I'd just like to know the possibilities, as I have already submitted my solution as stated above. However, what would you tell me to look at PyQt / Pyside code? Thank you for your willingness to help me!